# Is there any way to convert std::io::Error to failure::error::Error?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have this code:

```
let file = FileStorage {
   // ...
};

file.write("Test", bytes.as_ref())
    .map_err(|e| MultipartError::Payload(error::PayloadError::Io(e)))?;
```

It doesn't really matter in which context this code is written for my question so this is just for demonstration and I will not give any more details about the functionally and the context of this code.

`error::PayloadError::Io(e)` takes a `std::io::Error` struct, but the `ResultError` of my own type `FileStorage` takes an `failure::error::Error`.

I could change the `ResultError` of my type to be a `std::io::Error`, but this is for other reasons not possible in this project.

Since the two errors are external traits I cant implement one for each other.
Is there an easy way to convert the errors without creating my own error-type?

Comment: Try `std::io::Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e)`

Comment: You can try to [context](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Context.html) your errors with failure crate

Comment: What is `ResultError`? Where does `PayloadError` come from? Where does `MultipartError` come from?

Comment: *the two errors are external traits* — `io::Error` is not a trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the comment of [@AbhijitKadam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063250/abhijit-kadam) worked fine for me:

```
file.write("Test", bytes.as_ref())
                     .map_err(|e| MultipartError::Payload(error::PayloadError::Io(std::io::Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))))?;
```